# Volume Panel Android 7.1.1

Tags: 7.1-nougat

Ever since Android 7.1.1 I am unable to find the page (activity screen) to set, on one screen, the volume for the various audio outputs, such as notificatios, media, etc. Is there such a screen inherent in Android 7, or do I need to find an app for that.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is found under *Settings → Sound* i.e

[image]

If for some reason you can't find it or is hidden, then just grab a third-party activity launcher application from playstore e.g Quick shortcut to access `com.android.settings/com.android.settings.Settings$NotificationSettingsActivity`

1. Install [Quickshortcutmaker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?com.sika524.android.quickshortcut) from Playstore
2. Select normal search - under input box type **sound** and click search

[image]

3. In search results it will show Settings click it,  and expand the list you will find "Sound & Notification"  then click **try** (or create shortcut by pressing create).

[image]      [image]

Comment: I had "Volume" under "Settings/Sounds", but it looked like a heading, so I never clicked it. Not smart I suppose, but now I can set the volumes for "Notifications", "Media", and "System".  Great answer. Thanks.

Comment: Please don't forget to [accept](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) the answer if it solved your issue :)

Answer (score 0):

I had "Volume" under "Settings/Sounds", but it looked like a heading, so I never clicked it. Not smart I suppose, but now I can set the volumes for "Notifications", "Media", and "System".  Great answer from @xavier_fakerat. Thanks.